# Find dimension of the quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, ideals

Let $I = \{ f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x] :f(1)=f'(1)=0\}$. One can show that $I$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Thus, $\mathbb{C}[x]/I$ is a ring. Viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, what is the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x]/I$?

Let $f(x) \in I$, we must have $f(x) = (x-1)g(x)=xg(x) - g(x)$ for some $g(x)\mathbb{C}[x]$. In addition, we also have $g(1)=0$ since we need $f'(1) = 0$. How do I find the dimension from here? I am thinking about the possible remainder when I divide some polynomial $p(x)$ by $f(x)$, but I don't know the degree of $f(x)$.

Comment: Try answering the same question but with $1$ replaced by $0$.

Comment: Alternatively, note that $\Bbb{C}[x]$ is a PID. What is a generator for $I$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Mind elaborating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that a root $c \in F$ of a polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ is a repeated root of $f$ $ \iff c$ is also a root of $f'(x)$.  Thus, $I$ is the set of polynomials with $1$ as a repeated root.  Since $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a principle ideal domain, it must be the case that $I = \langle (x-1)^2 \rangle$.

Now think about the elements of $\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle (x-1)^2 \rangle$.  The equivalence classes of this quotient ring will be the possible remainders when polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are divided by $(x-1)^2$...

Comment: I actually just started reading about PID and I'm convinced that $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a PID since it's a Euclidean domain. But how did we conclude that $I = \langle (x-2)^2\rangle$? Is it because $(x-1)^2$ is the smallest degree polynomial in $I$?

Comment: Pretty much.  Notice in particular that any polynomial $g$ with $1$ as a repeated root can be written as $g(x) = (x-1)^2h(x)$ for some $h$ by the root-factor theorem.